# Field operator in Schrödinger picture

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In Schrödinger picture operators do not depend on time explicitly. Consider a free scalar field with Lagrangian density

$${\cal L} ~=~ \frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu} \phi\partial^{\mu}\phi-\frac{m^2}{2}\phi^2,$$

where $\phi=\phi(t,x,y,z)$. In quantum field theory we take it as an operator. Is this operator Schrödinger or Heisenberg one? How can we express free field Lagrangian in both pictures?

Comment: You're asking if $L$ is an operator in Schrodinger or Heisenberg picture?  Why would you care about this?

Comment: Yes, if $L$ is in Heisenberg picture, how can we write it in Schrödinger picture and vice versa. It's important while discussing scattering theory. Thank you.

Comment: In the Schrodinger (functional) representation, aren't you more interested in the Hamiltonian, because that's what you'll use to evolve states?  In the "coordinate" version of this, the canonical momenta go over into nice functional derivatives, explained in [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0212557v1.pdf) just like p=-id/dx

Comment: Twistor59, thank you for your comment. You are right, but Lagrange's formalism is more fundamental than Hamilton's one. Without knowing Lagrangian we can not write down Hamiltonian (sometimes it even not exist). While jumping from quantum mechanics to quantum field theory we have direct correspondence, for ex. coordinate becomes field but(!) is this field in Schroedinger picture or in Heisenberg one.

Comment: @zoroastra it is not true to say that a Lagrangian operator for a given system is more fundimental than the Hamiltonian counterpart. In fact, I would say the opposit is true due to the phase space used in each representation.

Comment: Killercam, thank you for your comment. I can not agree with you. I gave you the argument above. When the system has some symmetries, first we write down Lagrangian. After that we can determine generalized momentum and try to write Hamiltonian. In some cases it does not exist. A simple example is a relativistic particle with degenerate Hamiltonian $H=0$. Of course you can use another approach to describe such particle in phase space.

Comment: Why do write that coordinates become fields? As far as I’m concerned, coordinates stay coordinates. In fact, in quantum mechanics (QM), we have position and momentum operators, which are demoted to coordinates in quantum field theory (QFT) and become arguments to the creation and annihilation operators, so in a way there are more coordinates in QFT than in QM. Maybe you are thinking of [canonical quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory#Canonical_quantisation), in which classical fields become quantum fields, or operator fields?

Answer (score 7):

Like Josh said, if you want your operators $\hat{\phi}({\bf{x}},t)$to have a time dependence analogous to the time dependence of the classical fields $\phi({\bf{x}},t)$ which satisfy the equations of motion derived from the classical Lagrangian, then you're working in the Heisenberg picture, and the operator version of the classical equations of motion is just Heisenberg's equation $$ \dot{\hat{\phi}}=-i[\hat{\phi},H] $$  If, however, you want to work ***in the Schroedinger picture***, the operators will now be functions of position only, $\hat{\phi}({\bf{x}})$ and the time dependence is carried by the states.  In the approach known as the *functional Schroedinger picture*, they pick a fixed timeslice and define the space of states to be space spanned by the eigenstates of the field operator $$\hat{\phi}({\bf{x}})|\phi({\bf{x}})\rangle= \phi({\bf{x}})|\phi({\bf{x}})\rangle$$ So much for the eigenstates.  A generic state $|\Psi\rangle$ is a *functional* which maps a field $\phi({\bf{x}})$ to a number $$ \Psi[\phi({\bf{x}})] = \langle \phi({\bf{x}})|\Psi \rangle$$  This is entirely analogous to the QM relation $$\Psi({\bf{x}}) = \langle {\bf{x}}|\Psi \rangle$$ The field $\phi({\bf{x}})$ plays the role of the coord $\bf{x}$ in QM. In this representation, just as we have the representation $$\hat{\phi} \leftrightarrow  \phi({\bf{x}}) $$ so we also represent the conjugate variable by a [*functional derivative*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) $$\hat{\pi} \leftrightarrow  -i\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi({\bf{x}})} $$  This ensures that the canonical commutation relations are respected.  Moreover the time evolution of the states is now given by the *functional Schroedinger equation*

For standard perturbative calculations in scattering theory, however, it is much more convenient to use the slight modification of the Heisenberg picture known as the *interaction picture*.

Comment: Right. This is probably a good occasion to emphasize that the _Schrödinger picture_ should not be confused with the _Schrödinger representation._ The latter refers to the representation of the  momentum operator $\hat{p}=\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ as a position derivative (or its field theoretic generalization, cf. twistor59's answer).

Comment: @twistor59: Dear twistor59, recently I am studying Path integrals for a scalar field theory. In some books the eigenstates of field operators are introduced. But I am facing difficulty understanding them. Can you give me a reference where this topic is clearly discussed?
 Secondly, You have written: $ \hat{\Phi} (\textbf{x}) |\Phi(\textbf{x}) \rangle = \Phi(\textbf{x}) |\Phi(\textbf{x}) \rangle $ Does this mean that at a fixed time t we have different field operators for each position in the configuration space and for each field operator there is an eigenstate associated with an eigenvalue?

Comment: @Ome The eigenstates of the local field operators at a given spatial point i.e. $|\phi(\bf{x})\rangle$ aren't normalizable, but are still useful for formal manipulations.  The rigorous way to interpret them is to consider them as operator valued distributions: true operators are recovered by smearing with test functions.  This, together with the construction of the one particle state space and its extension to Fock space are discussed in [Bob Geroch's notes](http://strangebeautiful.com/other-texts/geroch-qft-lectures.pdf)

Comment: Dear Twistor59! This answer was very interesting to me as no QFT textbook I've ever read even mentioned the Schrödinger picture. What is still unclear to me is the exact nature of this functional. What equation does it come from? It can't have to do with the KG or Dirac equations because the solutions of those are the fields themselves. What does it have to do with transition amplitudes between multiparticle states? I would be very thankful if you could explain it to me with a little more examples.

Answer (score 3):

When the field $\phi$ is being written as a function of spacetime, with explicit dependence on time, then this field is said to be written in the Heisenberg picture.  You can see how this is consistent with the terminology used in non-relativistic quantum mechanics by recalling that (See e.g. Peskin and Schroeder eq. 2.43)
$$
  \phi(t,\mathbf x) = e^{i H(t-t_0)}\phi(\mathbf x, t_0)e^{-iH(t-t0)}.
$$
This shows that we can choose some time slice, say at time $t_0$, in Minkowski space at which be define our usual Shrodinger picture operators (the canonical degrees of freedom of the field theory) and at later times, these operator degrees of freedom are related to those at time $t_0$ via the usual Hamiltonian, unitary time evolution above.

In order to use notation that is more in line with that used in non-relativistic quantum mechanics (e.g. see Sakurai p. 82 bottom), you might be inclined to define
$$
  \phi^{(S)}(\mathbf x) = \phi(\mathbf x, 0), \qquad \phi^{(H)}(\mathbf x)(t)
$$
in which case the above time evolution relation would take the familiar form
$$
  \phi^{(H)}(\mathbf x)(t) = e^{iHt}\phi^{(S)}(\mathbf x)e^{-iHt}
$$
but this would be somewhat non-standard notation in field theory as far as I am aware.

Comment: Joshphysics, thank you very much for your answer. So, can we construct relativistic filed theory in Schroedinger picture? As we see there is an asymmetry between time and space in this picture.

Comment: @zoroastra Well I suppose it depends on what you mean by "we can construct...".  In principle, I can't see a reason why one cannot write any "Heisenberg picture equation" in the Shrodinger picture using manipulations similar to those in my reply if that's what you mean?  As for the "asymmetry" between space and time etc. I'd prefer to avoid commenting on qualitative statements like that in this case because I think it might just add to the confusion.

Comment: @zoroastra twistor59's response below addresses your last comment as well I'd say.

Comment: @joshphysics It bothers me that field operator at point $\vec{x}$ just depends on earlier field operators at the same position. Doesn't that mean that the fields at different points in space don't interact with each other? Or does the dependence from other points in space stem from the hamiltonian operator, which carries information about the energy in the whole space?

Comment: @Quantumwhisp The hamiltonian operator indeed is the object that contains the information about how the degrees of freedom (field operators at various spatial points) interact.  Think about, e.g., coupled harmonic oscillators in quantum mechanics -- in the Heisenberg picture, the position operator for the $i^\mathrm{th}$ oscillator would evolve according to $X_i(t) = e^{iHt}X_i(0)e^{-iHt}$ where the hamiltonian contains terms for the coupling.